# Argument type 'SecretSpec' does not conform to expected type 'Sequence'

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I want to encrypt a message on playground. my code is given below. i write another class to generate a secretkey. when convert the secret key into string, it gives error.

```
import UIKit

import Foundation
import CommonCrypto



class SecretSpec {
    var algorithm: String = "AES/ECB/PKCS5padding"
    var key = [UInt8]()


    func SecretSpec(key: [UInt8], algorithm: String){
        self.key = key
        self.algorithm = algorithm
    }

    func getAlgorithm() -> String {
        return self.algorithm
    }

    func getFormat() -> String {
        return "RAW"
    }

    func getEncoded() -> [UInt8] {
        return self.key
    }



    func hashCode() -> Int {
        var retval: Int = 0
        for i in 1...key.count-1 {
            retval = retval + Int(key[i]) * Int(i)
        }

        if (algorithm.lowercased() == "tripledes"){
            retval = retval ^ Int("desede".hashValue)
            return retval
        }else{
            retval = retval ^ Int(algorithm.lowercased().hashValue)
            return retval
        }
    }
}



extension String {

    func aesEncrypt(key: String, options:Int = (kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)) -> String? {
        if let keyData = key.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),
            let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),
            let cryptData = NSMutableData(length: Int((data.count)) + kCCBlockSizeAES128) {

            let keyLength = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)
            let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
            let algoritm: CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
            let options: CCOptions = UInt32(options)

            var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

            let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation, algoritm, options,
                                      (keyData as NSData).bytes, keyLength,
                                      nil, (data as NSData).bytes, data.count,
                                      cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
                                      &numBytesEncrypted)


            if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
                cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)

                var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: cryptData.length)
                cryptData.getBytes(&bytes, length: cryptData.length)

                var hexString = ""
                for byte in bytes {
                    hexString += String(format:"%02x", UInt8(byte))
                }

                return hexString
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}



func MD5(_ string: String) -> String? {
    let length = Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH)
    var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: length)

    if let d = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        _ = d.withUnsafeBytes { (body: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
            CC_MD5(body, CC_LONG(d.count), &digest)
        }
    }


    return (0..<length).reduce("") {
        $0 + String(format: "%02x", digest[$1])
    }
}



var mdT = "YourStrongKeyasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
var algorithm: String = "AES/ECB/PKCS7padding"

var s = MD5(mdT)
let buf: [UInt8] = Array(s!.utf8)

var skcSpec = SecretSpec()
skcSpec.SecretSpec(key: buf, algorithm: algorithm)



print("hello: \(skcSpec)")


skcSpec.getEncoded()
skcSpec.getFormat()
skcSpec.getAlgorithm()
skcSpec.hashCode()


let msg: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

msg.setValue("uttam kumar", forKey: "name")
msg.setValue("1001", forKey: "id")

let msgData: NSData
var msgStr: String = ""
var requestUrl: String = ""

do {
    msgData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: msg, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions()) as NSData
    msgStr = NSString(data: msgData as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String

} catch _ {
    print ("JSON Failure")
}


var skc = String(data: Data(skcSpec), encoding: .utf8)!
var encoded = msgStr.aesEncrypt(key: String(skc))!

print("encoded: \(encoded)")
```

I want to get String value of 'skc'. and print it. but it gives 'Argument type 'SecretSpec' does not conform to expected type 'Sequence'' error. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Data` does not have an initialiser for your custom type. Did you mean to get the encoded value?

```
var skc = String(data: Data(skcSpec.getEncoded()), encoding: .utf8)!
```